# Eclipse runs application as 64bit. JAR runs as 32 bit

Tags: eclipse, jar, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I'm using a 32-bit version of Eclipse on a 64-bit machine with "Windows 7 64-bit" installed.
I made a small application that creates a JFrame and shows in the title if the application is running as 64 or as 32 bit. I exported it as a .jar file. Executing the jar on any machine will always show "32". However, when I run the application directly from Eclipse it shows "64".

Why does Eclipse run the application as 64-bit but the JAR runs as a 32-bit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on the JVM with which the application is run.
In your case, under Eclipse, the application is run in 64-bit mode. That's because the JVM, with which the application is being run (through Eclipse), is a 64-bit JVM.
When you run it on other machines, you're running with a 32-bit JVM.

To see which JVM Eclipse is using, look at the Launch Configuration (the `Run` menu) and check out the JRE tab.